# Running Automation test in webdriverIO

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, automation, mocha.js

i am trying to run a test in webdriverio but always getting this error, how can i solve this problem thank you in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQljf.jpg)

Comment: Please add the error as text, image is hard to read and copy/paste the error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error - missing ) after argument list.